# How to install/enable `syslog.target`?

Tags: debian, systemd

The output I get when I run `systemctl list-units --type=target --all` includes the line

```
● syslog.target               not-found inactive dead   syslog.target
```

How do I install/enable whatever it is that provides `syslog.target`?

---

**FWIW**

- `syslog.target` does not show up in the output of `systemctl list-unit-files --type=target`.
- `syslog.target` is mentioned in three `/lib/systemd/*.service` files:

```
% ack '\bsyslog\.target\b' /lib/systemd
/lib/systemd/system/console-kit-daemon.service
3:After=syslog.target

/lib/systemd/system/hal.service
3:After=syslog.target acpid.service

/lib/systemd/system/ModemManager.service
3:After=syslog.target
```

- release info

```
% lsb_release -da
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 8.2 (jessie)
Release:    8.2
Codename:   jessie
```

Comment: What's your Debian version? Might that be leftover of some upgrade? I don't have `syslog.target` in 8.2 (jessie).

Comment: @TNW: 8.2 here also.  After digging around some more I found that `syslog.target` is obsolete.  Somehow my system does not know that...

Answer (score 3):

I had the same state and I thought there was something wrong but not necessarily. Then I found this link. (check **Systemd Journal Basics** section)
https://www.loggly.com/ultimate-guide/linux-logging-with-systemd/
It seems this is the current standard for logs with Systemd systems.
Inside the link, I found this rather clear statement: With systemd journal, there is no reason for a traditional syslog utility

Comment: This is a good answer but since the question is nearly 6 years old it might not have been applicable at the time.  Still, anyone searching this topic now will find it so that's good.

Answer (score 2):

Debian uses rsyslog by default now instead of syslogkd (which I'm sure you're looking for, not just "syslog"). This has been the case since Lenny.

If it's not installed, install rsyslog. It's a drop-in replacement for just regular syslog.